# Getters and Semaphores

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

Ive begun to learn about threading and semaphores in class and my teacher asked us an interesting question.  Why do semaphores not have any getter methods.  I thought about it and found no reasons for why this might be and couldn’t find anything online.  Is there a good reason for this?